# Swift 4 : how to wait for a MKMapView to be loaded before adding pins

Tags: swift, multithreading, view, wait

Well, the title is pretty self-explanatory. I have a little app with different views and it keeps crashing and I think it's because I'm trying to add pins on the map before the map is created (the debugger tells the object is nil). How can I wait for the map to be loaded and on the current view? Here is the code of the ViewController of my app:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {

          super.viewDidLoad()

          let coordinate_Mines = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.445258, longitude: 5.479400) //à remplacer ensuite par dernier coordonnés GPS utilisateur
          let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate_Mines, 1000, 1000)
          mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

          var pinCapteurTest: AnnotationPin!
          pinCapteurTest = AnnotationPin(title: "Capteur de test", subtitle: "Entrée de l'école", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.445202, longitude: 5.479456)) //coord capt test
          mapView.addAnnotation(pinCapteurTest)
     }
}
```

and here is my MainStoryBoard :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltAhN.png)

Thanks guys :)

Comment: I would assume that your code should works without problems, what's the crash says?

Comment: Unrelated: you should declare `pinCapteurTest` as `let pinCapteurTest = AnnotationPin(...`

Comment: Show the details of the error. it may not be the map view. try moving your map related code to viewDidAppear and see if that helps

Comment: Thx guys, please look at the comment on the answer of @mkamran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `ViewController` with `MKMapViewDelegate` and the below method is where you can add annotations.

```
public func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {

}
```

Set the `mapView` delegate to `self` in your viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks promising. However I still have the error "Thread 1 : Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". My current code is : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fa_iaLI3LuKdQcX9Bm6yUFTSb9Z7lcXD

Comment: are you sure your mapView outlet is connected in storyboard? have you tried commenting the code in viewDidLoad?